# Data format and stride

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

First of all, What is channel last format? Is it NHWC?

For the following code, how stride is calculated?

```
import torch
N, C, H, W = 10, 3, 32, 32
x = torch.empty(N, C, H, W)
print(x.stride()) # Ouputs: (3072, 1024, 32, 1)
```

**Output is (3072, 1024, 32, 1)**

When converted to channel last format, how stride is calculated here?

```
x = x.contiguous(memory_format=torch.channels_last)
print(x.shape) # Outputs: (10, 3, 32, 32) as dimensions order preserved
print(x.stride()) # Outputs: (3072, 1, 96, 3)
```

**Output is torch.Size([10, 3, 32, 32])
(3072, 1, 96, 3)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: *stride is the number of elements in the storage that need to be skipped over to obtain the next element along each dimension.*

---

I believe you're referring to this [tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/memory_format_tutorial.html).

Since every `tensor` references an underlying `storage`, you can have multiple `tensor`s referencing the same `storage` with different `stride`s and dimensions.

For e.g., I might have a 3x3 tensor:

```
[1 2 4
 0 4 5
 7 8 0]
```

but all that data is actually stored in a 1D contiguous `storage`, i.e. `[1 2 4 0 4 5 7 8 0]`. In order for the tensor to know how it should presented (i.e. 3x3), we need a `stride` property which is "the number of elements in the storage that need to be skipped over to obtain the next element along each dimension". The `stride` for this would be `(3,1)`, meaning I need to step over 3 elements in `storage` to get my next element in the first dimension and step over 1 element to get the next element in the second dimension. E.g.

- starts with 1. To get the next value in the row dimension, add 3 (as indicated by `stride`). So the third element after 1 in `storage` is 0.
- another e.g., let's start with the 2. To get the next value in the second dimension (col), add 1 in `storage`, which gives me 4.

That's the basics of how `stride` is calculated.

**Back to your original question,**

> N, C, H, W = 10, 3, 32, 32

To get the stride, say of N, and let's say N is the n'th image, then I need to skip over (32 x 32 x 3 = 3072) elements in order to get to the start of the next image. Hence why `stride() = (3072, 1024, 32, 1)` on the first dimension. The same logic applies to the other strides.

From the tutorial linked above, `channels last` is simply a different way to store the underlying `storage` object in memory (see the pic in link). The stride changes due to how the contiguous memory is allocated, but the way *we interpret and understand stride remains the same*.

Answer (score 1):

> First of all, What is channel last format? Is it NHWC?

Yes, additionally when you move from `NCHW` to `NHWC` in PyTorch the underlying memory is reordered and `stride` changes...

> For the following code, how stride is calculated?

### numpy introduction

`stride` defines how many `bytes` you have to jump to get to the next element in this axis, your snippet:

```
import numpy as np

N, C, H, W = 10, 3, 32, 32
x = np.empty((N, C, H, W))
print(x.strides)  # Ouputs: (24576, 8192, 256, 8)
```

So to get from element `[0, 0, 0, 0]` to element `[0, 0, 0, 1]` you need to make a jump of `8` bytes as that is the size of `np.float64` (default is `double`). To jump from `[0, 0, 0, x]` to `[0, 0, 1, x]` you need to go all over all elements in previous dimension so it is `32 * 8 = 256`. For the second dimension you have to go over `32 * 32 * 8 = 8192` and to jump across `N` you need to traverse `32 * 32 * 8 * 3 = 24576` bytes.

### In PyTorch

In Pytorch you don't jump across `bytes`, you jump across array elements instead (which IMO is easier **and is independent of underlying `type`**).

In standard with channels as the second dimension, you need to jump `1` element to move from `[0, 0, 0, 0]` to `[0, 0, 0, 1]` (self-explanatory, this is movement across on pixel in `W`), `32` elements to jump in the second to last dimension (`H`) and so on.

In `NHWC` format you have `(3072, 1, 96, 3)` for `(N, C, H, W)`. This means you jump `1` element to move across channels (as this is channels last), `3` elements to jump across `W`, `3 * 32` across `H` and `3 * 32 * 32` for `N`.